# Issue with Request Post request with JSON file - getting 500 error

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to use a Flask API with the following code

```
import requests
import json


def sendpushoverapi(user, title, content, priority=0, url='', urltitle=''):
    posturl = 'http://192.168.1.96:5000/spo'
    myobj = {
        "user":user,
        "title":title,
        "message_content":content,
        "priority":priority,
        "url":url,
        "url_title":urltitle
    }

    myjsonobj = json.dumps(myobj)   
    print(myjsonobj)
    x = requests.post(posturl, json=myjsonobj)

    print (x.text)
```

I am getting the following error from the API

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

However if I run this where I have basically copied out the output of the json.dumps element and created a new variable the call to the API works as expected.

```
import requests
import json


def sendpushoverapi(user, title, content, priority=0, url='', urltitle=''):
    posturl = 'http://192.168.1.96:5000/spo'
    myobj = {
        "user":user,
        "title":title,
        "message_content":content,
        "priority":priority,
        "url":url,
        "url_title":urltitle
    }
    
    myjsonobj = json.dumps(myobj)   
    print(myjsonobj)
    myjsonobjcopiedandpasted={"user": "ux1h23gmy1zn78abr27aukcrpuscym", "title": "Postman Test", "message_content": "This is a test of the Postman API", "priority": "0", "url": "http://google.com", "url_title": "Google"}
    x = requests.post(posturl, json=myjsonobjcopiedandpasted)

    print (x.text)
```

I am a complete loss as to why it is seemingly falling over when the supplied JSON should be the same (as I have copied and pasted it from the console in the latter and it works).

Comment: did you try calling the endpoint with the same set of params thru Postman or some HTTP client? to verify whether its working?

Comment: I did. I went through Postman with the same copy and paste and it all worked fine. It just seems to be when it is sent in variable form it fails.

Comment: You have an error on the server side, it means that you need to check the error output on the server side. You mentioned that you are working with Flask API, so I assumed that you have an access to the API server.

Comment: @Sherwood12 did you try comparing the output when you parse the dict into dumps and when you directly pass the copied json object?

Comment: The output from the json.dumps has been copied and pasted into the request and it works, but when taking out the interim step (i.e. passing as a varible) it fails.

Comment: and its literally the same content right? i mean the output in both the cases

Comment: Yep. That is why it is driving me crazy. If I copy and paste the output in as a new variable it works. Straight through it doesn't!

Comment: As suggested I have looked at the error files. This is what is showing up

Jan  9 13:32:33 raspberrypi4 gunicorn[31777]:   File "/var/www/homeapi/application.py", line 104, in spo
Jan  9 13:32:33 raspberrypi4 gunicorn[31777]:     user = content['user']
Jan  9 13:32:33 raspberrypi4 gunicorn[31777]: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: This is the relevant section of the API
```
@app.route('/spo', methods = ['POST'])
def spo():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    content = request.json
    user = content['user']

Answer (score 1):

I got to the bottom of it after much faffing.

Somehow the  `myjsonobj = json.dumps(myobj)` was re-encoding again so my json ended up full of slashes and extra ''

I just sent the request with `json=myobj` and it worked. I had thought I needed to convert the python library to JSON but it was already in the proper format.

Comment: Re-encoding is probably the most common pitfall with (de-)serialization. But your main outtake from here should still be alv's suggestion - when dealing with status 500 errors, ALWAYS look at the server-side logs, add debug print statements before problematic lines and such (or better yet, write tests for your API!). That largely turns your complex client-server problem into debugging any ol' Python code.